# How to change Tkinter combobox highlight background color

Tags: python, tkinter

In the below code, why am I not able to change the highlight background from blue to white?

As you can see I already set the

> 'highlightbackground': 'Yellow'

in

```
combostyle = ttk.Style()

combostyle.theme_create('combostyle', parent = 'alt',
    settings = {
        'TCombobox': {
            'configure': {
                'fieldbackground': 'white',
                'selectbackground': 'white',
                'selectforeground': 'black',
                'highlightbackground': 'Yellow'
            }
        }
    }
)

combostyle.theme_use('combostyle')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to change the highlight background from blue to white?

First of all, when you post your code - [make sure that someone can actually run it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce your problem!

If you asking about combobox field highlighting than you done it right with  lines:

```
'selectbackground': 'white',
'selectforeground': 'black'
```

It's really unclear, while you mentioned `'highlightbackground': 'Yellow'` , why you not been *able to change the highlight background from blue to white?* Perhaps you are doing something wrong when you apply this style?

And for what reason you use `highlightbackground`? As far as I know, there's no such an option (correct me if it there), so if you need to change highlight color to `yellow` in a combobox field, then change your `selectbackground` line to `'selectbackground': 'yellow'`.

If you want to change highlight color in a listbox - this thing is little tricky. According to tcl documentation [there](http://wiki.tcl.tk/37973) you can't do such a things directly!

> The combobox widget leverages the pre-ttk Listbox for its dropdown element and as such the 'option' command is currently required to set the listbox options.
>
> Whereas '-selectbackground' and '-selectforeground' (which apply to 'selected' text) can be used with the configure command, in using the options database for the associated listbox, we must use the appropriate database names of 'selectBackground' and 'selectForeground' respectively, and note that database names appear to be case sensitive (see http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/options.html for the full list).
>
> The above 'selectForeground' and 'selectBackground' options of the associated listbox are used to implement the standard 'hover' effect when selecting via mouse pointer.

So it can be solved like this:

```
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground', 'yellow') # change highlight color
root.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground', 'black') # change text color
```

Complete example:

```
# imports
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

import random
import string


# Main - application
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # style initiation
        self.style = self.get_style()
        self.style.theme_use('combostyle')
        self.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectBackground', 'yellow')
        self.option_add('*TCombobox*Listbox.selectForeground', 'black')

        # some other stuff
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        # frame
        self.main_frame = tk.Frame(self, bg='gray', relief='raised', borderwidth=10)
        self.combo_box = ttk.Combobox(self.main_frame)
        self.combo_box.pack()
        self.main_frame.pack()

        # insert something to combobox
        self.insert_something_to_combobox()


    def insert_something_to_combobox(self):
        self.combo_box['values'] = [gen_key() for _ in range(10)]

    @staticmethod
    def get_style():
        combo_style = ttk.Style()
        combo_style.theme_create('combostyle', parent='alt',
                                 settings={
                                    'TCombobox': {
                                        'configure': {
                                            'fieldbackground': 'white',
                                            'selectbackground': 'white',
                                            'selectforeground': 'black',
                                        }
                                    }

                                 }
                                 )

        return combo_style


def gen_key(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    # just to generate some random stuff
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lots CommonSense!

Comment: @Behseini, I'm glad to help and I'm curious, what was the problem you solved? And if you can spare some time - then please, edit and make your question more clear. Because I don't even know why you accepted my answer!